# Tutorials on FolioReader

Tags: android, epub

I am developing an EPUB reader application and I found this amazing library on Github. I searched a lot and I didn't find a single tutorial or example on how to use it. Do someone have any idea how to use its features?

Comment: Their [guide](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android#usage) helps you on  getting started with it.

Comment: @SauraThorat there is no guide there

Comment: They explain there how you can call `FolioReaderActivity` and pass in parameters like path of file. The 'usage' section which I linked certainly has all the information required for starting out.

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhThorat.... I downloaded the project and got a direction to work with the library.

Comment: @shubh,Did  you customize the Folioreaderactivity ?I am also working on same,can you help me

Comment: @honey, It's difficult to customise that library. I used textfairy open source project (I was working on OCR too) to reader epubs.

Comment: @Shubh,Thank you for your reply.I need to show epub file in an view,If you know any library that opens the epub in an view instead of an activity like in folio reader Please let me know.Thanks